# How to programmatically register a .NET MVC app to use Microsoft LiveId auth(without manually registering in Microsoft account development center)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, clientid

We register our application in the Microsoft account development center to get ClientID and SecretCode to redirect to microsoft authentication whilst logging in.
But, I need to register the application in the Microsoft account development center through code.

I should write an application and pass the required information (application name, redirect Url etc) and it should return the ClientID and SecretCode so that I can store in my database.

Can anybody help me to find the relevant SDK or approach to achieve this solution.

Thanks in advance

Ramesh